# Suitescript 2.0 update lookup field value

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, sublist, lookupfield

I need to get a lookup fields value from a line item on an SO and then update the corresponding line item in a PO. Fetching the value is not a problem, I'm using

`newSite = record.getSublistValue("item", "custcol_site", lineNum)`

to get the value - this returns the id of the lookup field object. However when I then try to update the field value on the PO using

```
loadedTransaction.setSublistValue({
    sublistId: "item",
    fieldId: "custcol_site",
    value: newSite,
    line: lineNum
});
```

Nothing happens, I don't get an error, however the field doesn't update either. How can I update the field using this ID value I've already fetched?

I'm also updating a number of other fields without issue following the same pattern, it's only the lookup field that's not updating successfully, so "lineNum" and fieldIds are not the problem as far as I can tell, I must just not be sending the correct information to update the lookup, however I can't find somewhere to tell me what information to send through.

Answer (score 0):

Inferring from the name `loadedTransaction` that you have called `record.load()` to retrieve that reference, you'll also need to then call `loadedTransaction.save()` to commit your changes to the database.

Comment: Yep, I'm saving the transaction and the other sublist fields are being updated correctly, only the lookup field isn't being updated.

Comment: Compare the permissions on the custom column to the permissions the script is using. If the field is Inline you can't update it. Beyond that I'm out of suggestions.

Comment: In additon to for sale, for purchase also check that the custom field isn't limited only to certain items.

Answer (score 0):

Are you committing the line item before saving the record ?
recordObj.commitLine('item');